# Develop layout for both 320dp and 360dp within RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

As I posted here [how-can-i-create-layout-for-both-320dp-and-360dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092965/how-can-i-create-layout-for-both-320dp-and-360dp). In that question I gave a simple example about two buttons. But Now I've my layout for 320dp and I couldn't create a layout for 360dp like Motorola Atrix. Because the solution was given was related for LinearLayout and my layout now is Relative. How can I avoid or fill the blank space at right?

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tapfast" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_logomaior"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_img_logomaior"
        android:src="@drawable/img_logomaior"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />    

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapcolor"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapcolor" />     

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapname"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapname"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapname" />       

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapgroup"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapgroup" />     

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_tap_2be"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_tap_2be"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_width_tap_2be"
        android:src="@drawable/tap_2be"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_tap_2be" />

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_bt_howtoplay"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_bt_howtoplay"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_bt_howtoplay"      
        android:src="@drawable/bt_howtoplay"        
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Motorola Atrix**

[image: Motorola Atrix]

**Samsung Galaxy SII**

[image: Samsung Galaxy SII]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to post your code for me to be sure.

But you should be able to add an attribute like this to your RelativeLayout:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

**EDIT:** I think if you put your 3 ImageViews inside of their own layout and set the gravity on the top level parent to be center horizontal it will keep all of your ImageViews in the same position relative to each other, but it will also scoot them over some so they are centered no matter which device you are running on.

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tapfast" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_logomaior"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_img_logomaior"
        android:src="@drawable/img_logomaior"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_img_logomaior"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />    

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapcolor"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapcolor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapcolor" />     

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapname"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapname"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapname" />       

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_mode_tapgroup"
        android:src="@drawable/mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_mode_tapgroup"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_mode_tapgroup" />     

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_tap_2be"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_tap_2be"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_width_tap_2be"
        android:src="@drawable/tap_2be"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_tap_2be" />

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_bt_howtoplay"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width_bt_howtoplay"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height_bt_howtoplay"      
        android:src="@drawable/bt_howtoplay"        
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think it's not the problem. Because I'm using fixed sizes (dp). just to justify my question, there are 3 images. Ok just take a look at my layout.xml

Comment: I think if you put the 3 images in their own sub layout you can use the center horizontal gravity to scoot them over to the middle. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html
and this one http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: No, my problem is howcome I can define a layout for 360dp such as Motorola Atrix?